# Are there any utilities for easily disabling/enabling extra hard drives?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, ssd, power-management

I just got an Asus G60 laptop, will be installing an SSD as the primary, and will use the existing HDD as a storage drive.

Is there a utility that I can use to turn off/disconnect the storage drive when I'm not using it?  Primarily I want to be able to conserve power when I'm mobile, since the battery life of this laptop is pretty weak.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [RevoSleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/) (have not used it, but your question made me look it up).
It would be good to remember that spinning down and restarting a drive often
is said to increase its wear. So, avoid doing changing its state frequently.

If its not going to be in use for a long time,
you could disable the drive from your laptop BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the built-in power manager will turn hard-drives off after a (configurable) period of inactivity. In Windows 7, this can be found at:

`Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings > Hard disk`

I have a similar setup on my desktop machine and occasionally there is a pause when accessing the main data HDD while it powers-up - so this definitely works.